# How to discover current role in Python Fabric

Tags: python, fabric

This is a very [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org) specific question, but more experienced python hackers might be able to answer this, even if they don't know Fabric.

I am trying to specify different behaviour in a command depending on which role it is running for, i.e.:

```
def restart():
    if (SERVERTYPE == "APACHE"):
        sudo("apache2ctl graceful",pty=True)
    elif (SERVERTYPE == "APE"):
        sudo("supervisorctl reload",pty=True)
```

I was hacking this with functions like this one:

```
def apache():
    global SERVERTYPE
    SERVERTYPE = "APACHE"
    env.hosts = ['xxx.xxx.com']
```

But that is obviously not very elegant and I just discovered roles, so my question is:

How do I figure out which role a current instance belongs to?

```
env.roledefs = {
    'apache': ['xxx.xxx.com'],
    'APE': ['yyy.xxx.com'],
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Update*: Just checked [the source code](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/1.4.2/fabric/state.py#L292) and it *seems* that this was already available as early as 1.4.2!

*update 2*: This seems *not* to work when using the `@roles` decorator (in 1.5.3)! It only works when specifying the roles using the `-R` command line flag.

For fabric 1.5.3 the current roles are directly available in `fabric.api.env.roles'. For example:

```
import fabric.api as fab

fab.env.roledefs['staging'] = ['bbs-evolution.ipsw.dt.ept.lu']
fab.env.roledefs['prod'] = ['bbs-arbiter.ipsw.dt.ept.lu']


@fab.task
def testrole():
    print fab.env.roles
```

Test output on the console:

```
› fab -R staging testrole
[bbs-evolution.ipsw.dt.ept.lu] Executing task 'testrole'
['staging']

Done.
```

Or:

```
› fab -R staging,prod testrole
[bbs-evolution.ipsw.dt.ept.lu] Executing task 'testrole'
['staging', 'prod']
[bbs-arbiter.ipsw.dt.ept.lu] Executing task 'testrole'
['staging', 'prod']

Done.
```

With this, we can do a simple `in` test in a fabric task:

```
@fab.task
def testrole():
    if 'prod' in fab.env.roles:
        do_production_stuff()
    elif 'staging' in fab.env.roles:
        do_staging_stuff()
    else:
        raise ValueError('No valid role specified!')
```

Comment: thanks for this update. my old answer is very out of date / irrelevant these days.

Comment: This also doesn't work with command line format `fab testrole:roles="staging,prod"`. Too limited for actual usage.

Comment: @Rockallite That is the syntax to pass in params to tasks. I did indeed find [your example in the docs](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/usage/fab.html?highlight=roles#roles-and-hosts). But I was unable to use that syntax to specify roles (see [transcript](https://gist.github.com/exhuma/8348976)). Why not simply use `-R`? Is it possible that the fabric docs are out of date?

Comment: @exhuma My bad. It should be `fab testrole:roles="staging;prod"`. Use semi-colon, not comma. And why not use `-R`? Because some times I have to use local tasks along side with remote tasks, e.g. `fab local_task remote_task:role="dev;cloud"`, where `local_task` is not allowed to assign a role.

Comment: @Rockallite hmm... I see... Interesting... I'll have to think about that how it would be implementable...

Comment: OMG. Too much typos. The previous example should be `fab local_task remote_task:roles="dev;cloud"`.

Answer (score 18):

For everyone else ever with this question, here is my solution:

The key was finding env.host_string.

This is how I restart different types of servers with one command:

```
env.roledefs = {
    'apache': ['xxx.xxx.com'],
    'APE': ['yyy.xxx.com']
}

def apache():
    env.roles = ['apache']

...

def restart():
    if env.host_string in env.roledefs['apache']:
        sudo("apache2ctl graceful", pty=True)
    elif env.host_string in env.roledefs['APE']:
        sudo ("supervisorctl reload", pty=True)
```

enjoy!

Comment: This will fail if I have same host associated with different roles and want to do different things depending on what role is currently executed :/

Comment: Fabric has changed a lot since I asked/answered this question, so I don't really understand your problem. It's easy to deal with hosts in multiple roles with my code above, simply change the if/elif into if, if, if... If you want to know how to make a command work for only a specific role, check out this new functionality: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.1/usage/execution.html#intelligently-executing-tasks-with-execute

Comment: I believe there is some kind of misunderstanding ;) What I was saying is that if you have one host for multiple roles (eg. `env.roledefs = {'apache': ['host1', 'host2'], 'APE': ['host1']}` and you execute your script for specific role, you do not have the ability to check which role specifically is being processed. Of course you can use `execute()` for creating "meta tasks", but this does not solve the issue (I would not call it a problem). I believe Fabric was not just designed for that and you need to deal with it in some other way (unless it was designed for it?).

Comment: Fabric can definitely handle the case you're describing, too. You can 'chain' multiple methods, use the first one to define which role you want to restart, then check the 'current role' in your restart function, for example. Maybe post your fabfile in a separate question, and people can try to help you make it work?

Comment: @Tadeck: I made a patch to fabric that adds a 'role' attribute to env.host_string https://github.com/fabric/fabric/pull/824

Comment: simply use `env.roles` (see my answer on this question).

Answer (score 12):

I didn't test it, but might work:

```
def _get_current_role():
    for role in env.roledefs.keys():
        if env.host_string in env.roledefs[role]:
            return role
    return None
```

Comment: simply use `env.roles` (see my answer on this question).

Answer (score 6):

The `env.roles` will give you the roles specified by -R flag or hardcoded in the script itself. It won't contain the roles specified per task using the command line or using `@roles` decorator. There is currently no way of getting this kind of information.

The next release of fabric (1.9 probably) will provide `env.effective_roles` attribute with exactly what you want - the roles being used for the currently executed task. The code for that has already been merged into master.

Have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/938).

Answer (score 0):

Using fabric 1.14.0 under Anaconda2 5.1.0... confirm the issue when using the `@roles` decorator... especially in the case that the `@roles` decorator is used with multiple arguments and then another task without the `@roles` decorator (or with different arguments) is called from within the first task. In my experience, this can have the effect of nonsensically mismatching the hosts, depending on how I discover the role (i.e. `role = env.effective_roles[0]`).

Note that `role = env.effective_roles[0]` does work well in simple situations, e.g. (a) `@roles` only specifies one role, and (b) the original task does not call another task.

Note also the situation where `-R` on command line does not override `@roles` and must use `task:roles=role1` instead: [How to run a @roles-decorated fabric task on only a single host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41291940/how-to-run-a-roles-decorated-fabric-task-on-only-a-single-host) ... also wondering how to pass multiple roles to an argument named `roles`... hmmm, but I digress.

Perhaps there is a better way, but documentation on `@roles` leaves one wanting. Next step is to probably read through the source code at this point.

In the meantime, I've hacked up the following workaround...

```
from fabric.api import env
from fabric.decorators import roles
from fabric.decorators import task


def get_host_roles(env, of=None, die=False):
    """
    Get the role(s) for a host at run time
    :param env: Fabric env
    :param of: tuple/set/list
    :param die: boolean
    :return: tuple(host, roles) or tuple(host, role)
    """
    host = env.host
    def valid(role):
        return host in env.roledefs[role]:
    roles = set(filter(valid, env.roledefs.keys()))
    if of:
        roles = tuple(roles & set(of)) # set intersection
        if len(roles) == 1:
            return host, roles[0]
        elif die:
            e = 'Host "%s" is not in just one of the provided roles: %s!' \
                % (host, repr(roles))
            raise Exception(e)
    return host, roles


_roles = ('role1', 'role2')


@task
@roles(*_roles)
def do_something_with_roles():
    host, roles = get_host_roles(env)
    # roles is a tuple with all of the roles the host is in.


@task
@roles(*_roles)
def do_something_with_roles_diy():
    host, roles = get_host_roles(env, _roles)
    # `roles` is a tuple with the set intersection of `_roles` and the
    # host's actual roles... so you handle the situation!
    if 'role1' in roles:
        # do whatever
        pass


@task
@roles(*_roles)
def force_single_role():
    host, role = get_host_roles(env, _roles, True)
    # this usage raises an exception in the instance that the host is not
    # exclusively in either 'role1' or 'role2'.
    # roles is a string with the role for that host.
```

Hope that helps.