# How to determine fabric role in fabfile to send specific files to hosts

Tags: python, fabric

I have an environment that sort of looks like this:

```
env.roledefs = {
    'cisco-collectors': ['hosta', 'hostb', 'hostc'],
    'brocade-collectors': ['hosta', 'hostd']
}
```

and I have some specific files that need to be sent to hosts in specific roles:

```
files = {
    'cisco-collectors': ['/path/to/filea', '/path/to/fileb'],
    'brocade-collectors': ['/path/to/filec', '/path/to/filed']
}
```

How do I write my sendFiles() function so that when a role is specified on the command line, or even with the `@roles()` decorator I'll be able to get the proper file list?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098912/how-to-discover-current-role-in-python-fabric) shows a way to determine if the host belongs to a role, but I need to get the role currently being executed so I know which file list to send.

Ideally it would look like this:

```
@roles('cisco-collectors', 'brocade-collectors')    
def sendFiles():
  for file in files[env.current_role]:
    put(file)
```

Answer (score 1):

`env.host_string.role` contains the current role in the newest `fabric` source (unreleased).

[The commit](https://github.com/flupke/fabric/commit/47650dc14f406bf56f6210744fd55dca3b7be58f)

Answer (score 0):

In my tests, I don't think you can reliably get the current role in 1.5. See Pavel's answer about how this will change. While this may seem inconvenient, I think the reason is that Fabric combines the list of hosts, so role doesn't carry over.

There is a workaround if you don't need to use the role functionality, though. You can create a task which alters the hosts list. This will **only** work for one role though!

```
from fabric.api import task, local, env

@task
def role1():
    env.current_role = 'role1'
    env.hosts.extend(['example.com'])

@task
def role2():
    env.current_role = 'role2'
    env.hosts.extend(['test.example.com'])

@task
def test():
    print env.current_role
    print env.hosts
```

If you now run `fab role1 test` you will see:

```
[localhost] Executing task 'test'
role1
['localhost', 'example.com']
[example.com] Executing task 'test'
role1
['localhost', 'example.com']
```

Not exactly what you were after ... but may help lead you to what will work.