# How to run a @roles-decorated fabric task on only a single host

Tags: python, fabric

I have a task decorated with `@roles` that I would occasionally like to run on a single host (for canary-testing deploys).

```
from fabric.api import *

env.roledefs = {
    'web-workers': ['django@worker1', 'django@worker2'],
    'some-other-role': ['django@worker2'],
}

@task
@roles('web-workers')
def bogomips():
    run('uptime')
```

The [docs for `@roles`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.12/api/core/decorators.html#fabric.decorators.roles) states that:

> ...barring an override on the command line, my_func will be executed against the hosts listed [in the role]...

But I can't get the "override" functionality mentioned here to work...  I've tried:

```
$ fab bogomips -H django@worker2
$ fab bogomips -R some-other-role
```

but it always executes on the entire role mentioned in the decorator...

What am I missing here?  How can I override where a `@roles`-decorated task is run?

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm encountering the same behavior. It seems to ignore the `--roles` flag when a task is decorated with roles('...'). For example, try your code with `--roles=NOT_A_ROLE`, and it should work without throwing any errors. Remove the `@roles('...') decorator from the task though, and it will throw an error (role doesn't exist). But at least the roles flag seems to work in that scenario. Definitely does not seem to be the behavior described by the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually the intended behavior, according to the [Execution model's Order of Precedence](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.0.0/usage/execution.html#order-of-precedence), and there's a slightly different syntax that you must use in this scenario.

So here's the command that doesn't work:

```
$ fab bogomips -R some-other-role # fabric ignores the -R values!
```

And here's the version that DOES work:

```
$ fab bogomips:roles=some-other-role
```

Here's the issue: [#308: @roles and @hosts decorators ignore command line options](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/308)

And the docs: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.0.0/usage/execution.html#order-of-precedence

> - Per-task, command-line host lists (fab mytask:host=host1) override absolutely everything else.
> - Per-task, decorator-specified host lists (@hosts('host1')) override the env variables.
> - Globally specified host lists set in the fabfile (env.hosts = ['host1']) can override such lists set on the command-line, but only if you’re not careful (or want them to.)
> - Globally specified host lists set on the command-line (--hosts=host1) will initialize the env variables, but that’s it.